# Converting a list containing integer lists of differing sizes into a data frame in R without any N/A values

Tags: r

I have something like this:

```
x1 <- list(1,2,3,4,5)
x2 <- list(1,4,7,8)
x3 <- list(5,6)
x4 <- list(9,0,0,5,6,7)
myList <- list(x1, x2, x3, x4)
```

I want to turn the list, 'myList' into a data frame where each row is a separate list, so row 1 only contains values for x1, row 2 only contains values for x2 and so on. However when I run a code like this:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(myList), nrow=length(myList), byrow = T))
```

It doesn't differentiate between lists and splits the lists so that if fits evenly. The examples that I saw online all show how to do it in a way that "empty" cells of the data frame are filled with N/A. However I want each cell to have a value inside it. How can I make it so that it makes a data frame of size (# of lists x length of largest list) and the smaller lists repeat their last value until they are of equal length as the largest list. So, with the above example something like this:

```
X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6
 1  2  3  4  5  5
 1  4  7  8  8  8
 5  6  6  6  6  6
 9  0  0  5  6  7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R,

```r
myList <- list(list(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 
               list(1, 4, 7, 8), 
               list(5, 6), 
               list(9, 0, 0, 5, 6, 7))

as.data.frame(t(sapply(myList, function(x){
    c(x, rep(tail(x, 1), max(lengths(myList)) - length(x)))
})))
#>   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
#> 1  1  2  3  4  5  5
#> 2  1  4  7  8  8  8
#> 3  5  6  6  6  6  6
#> 4  9  0  0  5  6  7
```

or purrr

```r
library(purrr)

myList %>% 
    map(~c(.x, rep(tail(.x, 1), max(lengths(myList)) - length(.x)))) %>% 
    map_df(~set_names(.x, paste0('V', seq_along(.x))))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 6
#>      V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  1.00  2.00  3.00  4.00  5.00  5.00
#> 2  1.00  4.00  7.00  8.00  8.00  8.00
#> 3  5.00  6.00  6.00  6.00  6.00  6.00
#> 4  9.00  0     0     5.00  6.00  7.00
```

Answer (score 1):

```
temp = lapply(myList, unlist)
L = max(lengths(temp))
data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(temp, function(x) c(x, rep(tail(x, 1), L - length(x))))))
#  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6
#1  1  2  3  4  5  5
#2  1  4  7  8  8  8
#3  5  6  6  6  6  6
#4  9  0  0  5  6  7
```

Answer (score 1):

I way to do it would be to comple your list before perfoming your code:

First I compute max length

```
max_len = max(sapply(myList, length))
```

Then I complete each list with thhe last element repeated

```
myList <- lapply(myList, function(x)c(x, rep(x[length(x)], max_len - length(x) )))
```

Finaly I use your code

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(myList), nrow=length(myList), byrow = T))
```